# Error al borrar Database|Schema directorio no existe

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, schema

La base de datos no se borra, utilicé el comando `Drop database test1;` con la query  `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'datadir'`, pero me devolvió el error:

> ERROR 3679 (HY000): Schema directory './test1/' does not exist

Obtuve el directorio donde se guardan las base de datos, efectivamente no esta pero, sin embargo cuando cuando hago un `show Databases | schemas` siguen apareciendo

La version de mysql es 8.0.23

Answer (score 0):

Tienes varias soluciones [Aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584458/error-dropping-database-cant-rmdir-test-errno-17)

Una de ella indica si tienes wamp ingresar al siguiente directorio

> C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\data

Después borrar la carpeta con el nombre de la base de datos.

Comment: Hola, había visto esas soluciones pero no funcionaban, Debe de ser un bug de mysql para homebrew ya que no aparecían los directorios para poder eliminarlos o los había eliminado y estaban en cache o no borraba bien las referencias. He reinstalado mysql y ya no aparecían bbdd borradas.